# Different Hash between ZipFile class archive and Windows archive

Tags: hash, compression, zip

I'm trying to compress files using C# with ZipFile class. The hash of this archive file is different from the file created with the windows utility (send to -> compressed (zipped) folder).
Does anyone know the settings used by windows for the zip files? I've tried different settings, but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the archive file you made decompress successfully? If so, then *you do not have a problem*. There is no expectation or requirement for different compression software to generate the same compressed data. Or even different versions of the same software. The only requirement is that the compression/decompression process be lossless.

In addition to the compressed data, the headers in the two zip files can be different in the versions of the zip format identified, whether local entry lengths and CRC are deferred to after the compressed data, if the zip64 format is used, etc., etc.

Comparing hashes of archive files is an entirely pointless thing to do.